# Return type for Boolean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Do I need to declare boolean hint in Typescript when fetchData could also return false? If so how do I do that?

For example:

```
async function fetchData(uuid): Promise<Item> {
    const result = await axios.get('http:///wwww.url-site.com/id/' + uuid);

    if (result.data.Status === "none") {
      return false;
    }

    return result.data
}
```

// Usage

```
const data : Item = await fetchData(id);
```

I get an error:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Item'.

Comment: what is the structure of return type `Item`, as boolean is not a return type of `Item`

Comment: @aRvi Is it not possible to declare OR type? eg: `Promise<Item | booleam>` ?

Comment: yes you can do that then
const data : any = await fetchData(id);
as return can be Item or boolean

Comment: @aRvi but that did not work. Same error

Comment: how about just rejecting the promise if the status is none ? that way the fetchData interface would be much cleaner

Comment: `const data : any = await fetchData(id); ` as return can be Item or boolean

Comment: @aRvi Don't use any. We use TypeScript to have strict typing. Using any is the opposite

Comment: `const data : (Item | boolean) = await fetchData(id); `
then you use this instead of any

Comment: You can just leave out the type annotation when calling the function. Because of the way types flow in TypeScript, the transpiler knows the correct type without any annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) to indicate that either an `Item` or a `boolean` is returned:

```js
async function fetchData(uuid): Promise<Item | boolean> {
    ...
}
```

That said, it would be more customary to return `null` instead of `false` to indicate the absence of a value:

```js
async function fetchData(uuid): Promise<Item | null> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @CristianTraìna The function is `async` so the promise wrapping is not needed.

Comment: @NineBerry Thanks, been spending too much time with overly similar languages lately :)

Comment: So in that case, it would be like this? `const data : Item | null  = await fetchData(email);`

Comment: Yes, although you can leave out the type annotation if you prefer.